# Parsing Calculation from Text Input Layout .xml

Tags: java, android, xml

This is sending me crazy. It works from a basic xml using EditText fields but not from com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText 
The app crashes with the logcat pointing to NullPointerException when attempting to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.widget.EditText.toString()' on a null object reference
I've tried all the suggestions listed under this problem but none seem to deal with TextInputEditText. 
Why is it pointing to the EditText widget when it will only accept getEditText command?

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/inputa"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="118dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/inputb"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/textInputEditText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
        android:hint="@string/input1"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/inputb" />

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/inputb"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="27dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textInputEditText"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/inputa">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/input1"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_marginBottom="53dp"
        android:text="@string/calculate"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/rrr"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/rrr"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textInputEditText" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rrr"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="118dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.me.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextInputLayout inputa;
    TextInputLayout inputb;
    Button button;
    TextView rrr;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        inputa = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.inputa);
        inputb = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.inputb);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        rrr = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rrr);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String input = inputa.getEditText().toString();
                double x = Double.parseDouble(input);
                input = inputb.getEditText().toString();
                int y = Integer.parseInt(input);

                double total = x * y;
                rrr.setText((int) total);

            }

        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Currently as per your code you are taking the instance of Edit text as a input. input = inputb.getEditText().toString(); To get the value from edit text, you need to do this way, inputb.getEditText().getText().toString().

Comment: Thanks, I replaced getText with get EditText when I used TextInputLayout because it threw up an error. I suspected getText was needed but could work out how. The parentheses did the trick!